# How to correctly bind Google account to the Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 19.10, google, google-drive

I have just installed Kubuntu 19.10 on the virtual machine.
I need to bind Google account to KDE to use Google services. So I did the following:

1. started Online Accounts wizard from the KDE menu (the `kcmshell5 kcm_kaccounts` was really launched by it);
2. clicked Add, selected Google;
3. provided my correct and valid credentials for KDE Online Accounts in the opened authentication window.

Then the following window popped out:

> [image: Web authentication for google]
>   ⚠️
>   Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
>   This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

When I close this window, the second window appears:

> Unable to finish - System Settings Module
>
> There was an error while trying to process the request: Access grant not present

What is wrong?

Notes:
1. I can login to this e-mail account using plain authentication for IMAPS, 2FA is disabled.
2. This my question is a result of [a in-comment discussion](https://askubuntu.com/q/1222882/66509) about working Google Drive integration to KDE out-the-box.

---

Package details (extra spaces removed by hand):

> ```
> $ dpkg -l | grep -i google
> ii  fonts-noto-color-emoji       0~20180810-1          all    color emoji font from Google
> ii  fonts-roboto-slab            1.100263+20170512-1   all    Google's signature family of fonts (slab)
> ii  fonts-roboto-unhinted        2:0~20170802-3        all    Google's signature family of fonts (unhinted)
> ii  libgoogle-gson-java          2.8.5-3               all    Converts Java objects into their JSON representation
> ii  libguava-java                19.0-1                all    Suite of Google common libraries for Java
> ii  libkpimgapi-data             19.04.3-0ubuntu1      all    Google API library for KDE -- data files
> ii  libkpimgapicalendar5:amd64   19.04.3-0ubuntu1      amd64  library to integrate with Google Calendar service API
> ii  libkpimgapicontacts5:amd64   19.04.3-0ubuntu1      amd64  library to integrate with Google Contacts service API
> ii  libkpimgapicore5:amd64       19.04.3-0ubuntu1      amd64  core library to integrate with Google service APIs
> ii  libkpimgapidrive5:amd64      19.04.3-0ubuntu1      amd64  library to integrate with Google Drive service API
> ii  libkpimgapitasks5:amd64      19.04.3-0ubuntu1      amd64  library to integrate with Google Tasks service API
> ii  plasma-browser-integration   5.16.5-1ubuntu1       amd64  Chromium, Google Chrome, Firefox integration for Plasma
> ```
>
> ```
> $ dpkg -l | grep -i kio
> ii  kde-cli-tools-data             4:5.16.5-0ubuntu1    all    tools to use kioslaves from the command line
> ii  kio                            5.62.1-0ubuntu1      amd64  resource and network access abstraction
> ii  kio-audiocd                    4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1   amd64  transparent audio CD access for applications using the KDE Platform
> ii  kio-extras                     4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1   amd64  Extra functionality for kioslaves.
> ii  kio-extras-data                4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1   all    Extra functionality for kioslaves data files.
> ii  kio-gdrive                     1.2.7-0ubuntu1       amd64  KIO access for GDrive
> ii  kio-ldap                       19.04.3-0ubuntu1     amd64  library for accessing LDAP - development files
> ii  kio-sieve                      4:19.04.3-0ubuntu1   amd64  Sieve mail filtering language support for kdepim, development files
> ii  libkf5kiocore5:amd64           5.62.1-0ubuntu1      amd64  resource and network access abstraction (KIO core library)
> ii  libkf5kiofilewidgets5:amd64    5.62.1-0ubuntu1      amd64  resource and network access abstraction (KIO file widgets library)
> ii  libkf5kiogui5:amd64            5.62.1-0ubuntu1      amd64  resource and network access abstraction (KIO gui library)
> ii  libkf5kiontlm5:amd64           5.62.1-0ubuntu1      amd64  resource and network access abstraction (KIO NTLM library)
> ii  libkf5kiowidgets5:amd64        5.62.1-0ubuntu1      amd64  resource and network access abstraction (KIO widgets library)
> ii  qml-module-org-kde-kio:amd64   5.62.0-0ubuntu1      amd64  provides integration of QML and KDE Frameworks - kio
> ```

Comment: Related: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=414219 ?

Comment: And https://phabricator.kde.org/T12486

Comment: In Kubuntu 20.04 (VM), there's only "owncloud" at least for me. Nothing else.